# Need advice on custom class

Tags: xetex, header-footer, environments, document-classes

First thank you for all the stuff I can read out there. It is so helful that I wouldn't have been able to do my first class without it.

Here is my very small work. I would like your advice. What do you think of the code? Is it reliable?
I'm a french math teacher in middle school (what we call here 'collège'), that is 11 to 15 year old pupils. I intend to write all my lessons, exams and solutions with it.

It is to be compiled using XeTeX.

There is a base.cls file, which is the base of the other classes. It sets up all the base elements such as language, fonts, units. Options are :

- dys: set font to OpenDyslexic
- print: remove links and set serif font, except if dys option is activated too
- nb: the document switches to gray mode (nb for 'noir et blanc' which means 'black and white')

Then the corrige.cls ('corrige' is for 'solution' in english) is based on base.cls and adds some fancy headers and footers plus a couple of environments. It passes the same options to the base class.

Here are the classes and a quite minimal working example.

Please let me know any comment you may have. Also, this is my first post so please excuse me if any of the formatting is not correct.

Ivan

base.cls:

```
% Classe définie pour compilation avec XeTeX

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{base}[2020/05/10 v0.2 Classe de base pour les cours, les évals et les corrigés]

% Options
% dys : utilise la font OpenDyslexic pour le texte et pour les maths
% nb : passe le document en nuances de gris (pour imprimer ou tester l'impression)
% print : désactive les liens (pour imprimer)

% Au cas où le titre, la date ou l'auteur ne seraient pas spécifiés.

\def\thedate{%
    \makeatletter
        \@date
    \makeatother
}

\def\thetitle{%
    \makeatletter
        \@title
    \makeatother
}

\def\theauthor{%
    \makeatletter
        \@author
    \makeatother
}

% On définit la police par défaut
\def\DocMainFont{Latin Modern Sans}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Gestion des options %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Si l'option 'dys' est passée à la classe, la police par défaut devient OpenDyslexic
\DeclareOption{dys}{\def\DocMainFont{OpenDyslexic}}

% Si l'option 'print' :
%   - polices avec empattements sauf si dys est passé en option
%   - liens désactivés
\DeclareOption{print}{%
    %\def\dysfalse{\let\def\DocMainFont{Linux Libertine G}\relax}
    \makeatletter
        \@ifclasswith{base}{dys}{}{\def\DocMainFont{Linux Libertine G}} 
    \makeatother
    %\def\DocMainFont{Linux Libertine G}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{draft}{hyperref}
}

% Si l'option 'nb' est passée à la classe, on active l'option gray de xcolor
\DeclareOption{nb}{\PassOptionsToPackage{gray}{xcolor}}

\ProcessOptions\relax


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Initialisation  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Classe article et taille de police par défaut
\LoadClass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% geometry
\RequirePackage[hmargin=2cm,bmargin=3cm,tmargin=4.5cm,centering]{geometry}

% Polices pour le texte (polices pour les maths dans la section « Maths »)
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{\DocMainFont}


% Localisation
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
% Si une autre langue doit être utilisée, penser à changer la locale de siunitx également
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

% Liens
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Graphismes, couleurs et ornements  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Tikz charge aussi graphicx et xcolor
% On charge donc xcolor avant pour mettre d'autres options
\RequirePackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{tikzpagenodes}

%\usetikzlibrary{calc}  % Inutile ?

% Chemin par défaut pour les images
\graphicspath{{./images/}}

% Jeu de couleurs personnalisées
\definecolor{BluePen}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\definecolor{RedPen}{RGB}{240, 50, 50}
\definecolor{GreenPen}{RGB}{20, 140, 20}
\definecolor{BlackPen}{RGB}{40, 40, 40}
\definecolor{OrangePen}{RGB}{230, 150, 10}
\definecolor{LightGreen}{RGB}{25,170,75}

% Pour les ornements (à charger après xcolor)
\RequirePackage{pgfornament}


%%%%%%%%%
% Maths %
%%%%%%%%%

%\RequirePackage{mathtools}     % À tester. Si utilisé, supprimer amsmath en-dessous puisqu'il est déjà chargé par mathtools mais laisser mathtools avant ntheorem
\RequirePackage{amsmath}        % À mettre avant unicode-math et ntheorem

% Pour les theorem personnalisés
\RequirePackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}

% Pour les maths en Unicode (remplace amsfonts, amssymb & co)
\RequirePackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}

% Polices
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathcal,\mathbfcal},StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math} % jeu spécial pour mathcal

% Police sans empattements


% Scratch 3
\RequirePackage{scratch3}

% Gestion des unités (voir plus bas « Commandes personnalisées »)
\RequirePackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%      Divers      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------
% Personnalisation des listes
%----------------------------

% Liste ordonnées personnalisées
\RequirePackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

% Hauteur de séparation des éléments de liste
\setlist{itemsep=.3em}

% Indentation des listes
\setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=2em}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=\parindent,leftmargin=2.7em}

%-------
% Divers
%-------

% Pour la mise en page sur plusieurs colonnes
\RequirePackage{multicol}

% Pour de jolis tableaux
\RequirePackage{booktabs}

% Espacement des lignes
\RequirePackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Pas d'indentation pour les nouveaux paragraphes
\setlength\parindent{0pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Commandes personnalisées  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\prl}{/\!/\ }       % droites parallèles

% Unités \u...
\newcommand{\ucm}[2][]{\SI[#1]{#2}{\cm}}    % centimètres
\newcommand{\um}[2][]{\SI[#1]{#2}{\m}}  % mètres
\newcommand{\ug}[2][]{\SI[#1]{#2}{\g}}  % grammes
\newcommand{\ukg}[2][]{\SI[#1]{#2}{\kg}}    % kilogrammes
\newcommand{\usm}[2][]{\SI[#1]{#2}{\square\m}}  % mètres carrés (square meters)

\newcommand{\aire}[1]{{\mathscr{A}}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\airet}[1]{\mathscr{A}_{\text{#1}}}

\newcommand{\peri}[1]{\mathscr{P}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\perit}[1]{\mathscr{P}_{\text{#1}}}

% Théorème de Thalès (double égalité)
\newcommand{\tthales}[6]{\frac{#1}{#2} = \frac{#3}{#4} = \frac{#5}{#6}}
\newcommand{\dthales}[4]{\frac{#1}{#2} = \frac{#3}{#4}}

\color{BlackPen}
```

corrige.cls:

```
% Classe définie pour compilation avec XeTeX

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{corrige}[2020/05/10 v0.2 Classe pour les corrigés]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Initialisation  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% On passe les options non spécifiques à la classe de base
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{base}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Et on charge la classe de base
\LoadClass{base}

% Puis viennent les spécificités de la classe corrigés

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%      Header and footer      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{lastpage}

% Header

\newcommand\Header{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[LimeGreen]
    (current page.north west) -- ([xshift=5cm]current page.north) -- ([xshift=3cm,yshift=75pt]current page.north|-current page text area.north) -- ([yshift=75pt]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle ;
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=north west, xshift=55pt,yshift=-15pt] at (current page.north west) {\Huge \thetitle} ;
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{BlackPen},anchor=north east,xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-17pt] at (current page.north east) {\huge Correction} ;
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{LimeGreen},anchor=north west, xshift=55pt,yshift=-55pt] at (current page.north west) {\large \thedate} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Footer

\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \fill[LimeGreen]
    (current page.south east) --
    ([yshift=-30pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) --
    ([yshift=-30pt,xshift=7cm]current page.south|-current page text area.south) --
    ([xshift=5cm]current page.south) --
    cycle ;
    \node[xshift=-2cm,yshift=.9cm,font=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{white}] at (current page.south east) {\large Page \thepage\ sur \pageref*{LastPage}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  Environnements personnalisés  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Exercice

\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{exo}{Exercice}
\newtheorem{eno}{Énoncé}
\newtheorem{corexo}{Correction de l'exercice}
\newtheorem{coreno}{Correction de l'énoncé}
\newtheorem{coract}{Correction de l'activité}

\newcommand{\arrowtitle}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[#2] (0,0) rectangle (4,.8) -- (4.3,.4) -- (4,0) ;
    \draw (.2cm,.4) node[anchor=west,font=\scshape\selectfont\color{white}]{\Large #1} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \medskip

}

\newcommand{\lignedefin}[1]{
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[#1] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,.33mm) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}


\newenvironment{activite}{\arrowtitle{Activité}{LimeGreen}}{\lignedefin{LimeGreen}}
%\newenvironment{jesaisfaire}{\arrowtitle{Je sais faire}{LimeGreen}}{\lignedefin{LimeGreen}}
%\newenvironment{exercices}{\arrowtitle{Exercices}{OrangePen}}{\lignedefin{OrangePen}}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\newenvironment{jesaisfaire}{%
    \mdfsetup{%
        backgroundcolor=LimeGreen!10,%
        roundcorner=5pt,%
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt,rounded corners=5pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=LimeGreen!80]
            {\strut \color{white} \large\sffamily\scshape \hspace*{.2cm}Je sais faire\hspace*{.2cm}};}
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=LimeGreen!40,%
        linewidth=1pt,topline=true,
        frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}
}

\newenvironment{exercices}{%
    \mdfsetup{%
        backgroundcolor=OrangePen!10,%
        roundcorner=5pt,%
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt,rounded corners=5pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=OrangePen!80]
            {\strut \color{white} \large\sffamily\scshape \hspace*{.2cm}Exercices\hspace*{.2cm}};}
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=OrangePen!40,%
        linewidth=1pt,topline=true,
        frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\Header\Footer}}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\Header\Footer}

\color{BlackPen}
```

working example:

```
\documentclass{corrige}

\title{Puissances de dix}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}    

\begin{jesaisfaire}
    \begin{coreno}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $10^5 = 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 = 100\,000$
            \item $10^7 = 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 \times 10 = 10\,000\,000$
            \item $10^3 = 10 \times 10 \times 10 = 1\,000$
        \end{itemize}
    \end{coreno}

    \begin{coreno}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item $10^{-2} = 0,1 \times 0,1 = 0,01$
            \item $10^{-5} = 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 = 0,000\,01$
            \item $10^{-7} = 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 \times 0,1 = 0,000\,000\,1$
        \end{itemize}
    \end{coreno}
\end{jesaisfaire}

\begin{exercices}
    \begin{corexo}
        \hfill\vspace*{-2em}    
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Cent : $10^2$
                \item Un millième : $10^{-3}$
                \item Dix mille : $10^4$
                \item Dix : $10^1$
                \item Un dixième : $10^{-1}$
                \item Un million : $10^6$
                \item Dix millions : $10^7$
                \item Un centième : $10^{-2}$
                \item Mille : $10^3$
                \item Un milliard : $10^9$
                \item Dix milliards : $10^{10}$
                \item Un millionième : $10^{-6}$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{corexo}

    \bigskip

    \begin{corexo}
        \hfill\vspace*{-2em}    
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $10^0 = 1$
                \item $10^{-1} = 0,1$
                \item $10^{-7} = 0,000\,000\,1$
                \item $10^9 = 1\,000\,000\,000$
                \item $10^{-4} = 0,000\,1$
                \item $10^1 = 10$
                \item $10^5 = 100\,000$
                \item $10^3 = 1\,000$
                \item[] \phantom{$10^{-4} = 0,000\,1$}
                \item[] \phantom{$10^1 = 10$}
                \item[] \phantom{$10^5 = 100\,000$}
                \item[] \phantom{$10^3 = 1\,000$}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{corexo}

    \bigskip

    \begin{corexo}
        \hfill\vspace*{-2em}    
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item $10^3 < 2\,345 < 10^4$
                \item $10^5 < 115\,000 < 10^6$
                \item $10^{-3} < 0,001\,57 < 10^{-2}$
                \item $10^4 < 43\,000 < 10^5$
                \item $10^{-4} < 0,000\,5 < 10^{-3}$
                \item $10^{5} < 127\,560 < 10^{6}$
                \item $10^{-5} < 0,000\,07 < 10^{-4}$
                \item $10^{3} < 1\,032,1 < 10^{4}$
                \item $10^{2} < 145,308 < 10^{3}$
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
        \end{corexo}

\end{exercices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Quick reaction: these look nicely structured, and well commented, allowing others to follow the logic clearly.  One suggestion: Add `\endinput` at the end of the two `.cls` files.  Sometimes when sending files through email, garbage gets tacked onto the end, and `\endinput` is a reliable way to say "ignore this junk."

Comment: Thank you Barbara.